# how to avoid the same thing being printed over and over?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

```
case 4:
        {
            string bookTitleDel;
            int bookPageNDel;
            int bookReviewDel;
            float bookPriceDel;

            cout << "\nPlease Enter the Title to be Deleted: ";
            cin >> bookTitleDel;
            cout << "\nTotal Number of Pages of the Book to be Deleted: ";
            cin >> bookPageNDel;
            cout << "\nPlease Enter Rating (stars): ";
            cin >> bookReviewDel;
            cout << "\nPlease Enter Price: ";
            cin >> bookPriceDel;

            for(int i=0;i<MAX_BOOKS;i++)
            {
                if((books[i].bookTitle!=bookTitleDel) && (books[i].bookPageN!=bookPageNDel) && (books[i].bookReview!=bookReviewDel) && (books[i].bookPrice!=bookPriceDel))
                {

                    cout<<"\n\nBook Doesnt Exist\n";
                    continue;

                }

            }

            for(int i=0; i<MAX_BOOKS; i++)
            {
                if((books[i].bookTitle==bookTitleDel) && (books[i].bookPageN==bookPageNDel) && (books[i].bookReview==bookReviewDel) && (books[i].bookPrice==bookPriceDel))
                {
                    a=i;
                    books[i]= {};
                    cout << "\nBook Deleted\n";
                    for(int k=a; k<MAX_BOOKS-1; k++)
                    {
                        books[k]=books[k+1];
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

            break; //break to exit switch case #4.
```

this code prints "book doesnt exists" 10 times, if it doesnt exist. How to avoid it? I am comparing the inputted values with the values that I had already added with the "add book" option not shown here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to print 'Book Doesn't Exist' only if NONE of the entries match, not every time there is no match.

So set a boolean variable to true (and break) if there is a match, and if after the loop ends there is no match THEN you print.

EDIT: Pseudocode

```
        boolean foundMatch = false;
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_BOOKS;i++)
        {
            if((books[i].bookTitle==bookTitleDel) && (books[i].bookPageN==bookPageNDel) && (books[i].bookReview!=bookReviewDel) && (books[i].bookPrice==bookPriceDel))
            {
                foundMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundMatch)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nBook Doesnt Exist\n";
        }
```

By the way, your code had a bug in it. If the condition for equality is `a1 == a2 && b1 == b2 && c1 == c2`, then the negation of that (false if that was true) is `!(a1 == a2 && b1 == b2 && c1 == c2)` NOT `a1 != a2 && b1 != b2 && c1 != c2`.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, but have no clue how to? Would you mind helping?

Comment: @patashu I found a different way by putting in a counter inside my for loop, but I got the idea from your answer, Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 2 for loops, use one for loop and use the boolean variable as Patashu told.

```
    switch = false

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_BOOKS; i++)
    {
        if((books[i].bookTitle==bookTitleDel) && (books[i].bookPageN==bookPageNDel) && (books[i].bookReview==bookReviewDel) && (books[i].bookPrice==bookPriceDel))
        {   
            switch = True
            a=i;
            books[i]= {};
            cout << "\nBook Deleted\n";
            for(int k=a; k<MAX_BOOKS-1; k++)
            {
                books[k]=books[k+1];
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    if (switch == False)
     cout<<"\n\nBook Doesnt Exist\n";
```